# Web page not fitting to width on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a web page that's 320px wide so I want it to fit entirely on the screen but instead theres a bunch of white space to the right of it, works perfectly fine on the Iphone. I've using the Viewport Metadata fix (meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; width=320") to adjust it, but that doesn't do anything.

Please help in suggesting a solution to this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this :

`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

and

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```